# How to split vector<char> into strings using delimeter

Tags: c++, delimiter

I have a vector of characters which contains some words delimited by comma. 
I need to separate  text  by  words  and add those words to a list.
Thanks.

```
vector<char> text;
list<string> words;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd do it something like this:

```
while ((stop=std::find(start, text.end(), ',')) != text.end()) {
    words.push_back(std::string(start, stop));
    start = stop+1;
}
words.push_back(std::string(start, text.end()));
```

Edit: That said, I have to point out that the requirement seems a bit odd -- why are you starting with a `std::vector<char>`? A `std::string` would be much more common.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<char> text = ...;
list<string> words;

ostringstream s;

for (auto c : text)
    if (c == ',')
    {
        words.push_back(s.str());
        s.str("");
    }
    else
        s.put(c);

words.push_back(s.str());
```

Comment: incomplete type is not allowed while using ostringstream

Comment: @jjjojjjooo: you need to include `<sstream>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to code this simple psuedocode and see how it goes

```
string tmp;
for i = 0 to text.size
    if text[i] != ','
       insert text[i] to tmp via push_back
    else add tmp to words via push_back and clear out tmp
```